# vrapper can it use standard plugins of vim like cscope and doxygen

Tags: eclipse, vim

Is there any standard path for vim plugins in vrapper. Like vim which as ~/.vim/plugin/ where custom plugins can be placed and commands can be used from VIM

The plugins that I wanted to use are cscope and doxygen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this pull request for the Sneak plugin](https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper/pull/764) and [this request to port the Abolish plugin](https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper/issues/636), Vim plugins need to be ported for Vrapper (basically rewriting the plugin functionality in Java, using Eclipse APIs or abstractions offered by Vrapper itself). I don't use Vrapper, but I'd guess that only simple remappings (via `:map` commands) are possible in the `.vrapperrc`. Anything beyond that would require a reimplementation of most of Vim's internals and the Vimscript language, and none of that is fully specified (beyond what's mentioned in Vim's `:help`).

Comment: Vrapper dev here; your answer is correct. Vrapper does not support Vimscript and hence no "real" Vim plugins.

Comment: Ah, glad I could help! Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.